# linux kernel not booting after building from git checkout

Tags: android, linux, git, linux-kernel, diff

I have a weird issue here!! 
I am building kernel for an android system.
I am able to build the kernel from a local copy and then generate android boot images which work fine on my device. 
If I check in this code to git, and then checkout another instance and follow the same build procedure , the image is not booting.

so far I have verified/Tried,

- it is not a problem with boot image creation
- I removed the .gitignore itself so that all files in local copy are checked in(checking in everything that is left after a make clean)
- using the meldiff tool, tried comparing the  checked in and checked out sets of kernel source, and found no difference
- In meldiff, If I do a high level copy(overwrite of checked out with original), everything starts working.
- I tried using the trial version of kaleidoscope diff tool on mac to compare the source. It did not find any difference that may have been missed by the meldiff

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Is toolchain the same? When creating `boot.img` -- is your kernel in the same location as for local copy case? Compare also `System.map` file with one from local copy build.

Comment: @Sam Hi Sam, Thank You.The toolchain is exactly the same. system.map do not show any difference as well. As for the location of kernel(the entire source code including android and kernels of other devices)- local copy and the checked-out version follows the same directory structure.The checked out version lies a few directories deep from the root compared to local copy. is that going to make any difference

Comment: First we need to be sure that the problem in the kernel and not in some outside configuration (like Android tools). Can you try to run `sha1sum` for `zImage` from both local and git kernel and compare those sums? It will help to localize the issue.

Comment: @Sam Thank you Sam.Seems like it is a git issue, and occurs because of the way I first added the the kernel source form the local copy to the git repo.
Here is what I have been doing. The local copy is a copy of the kernel source I received from oem(which was a git clone, has the .git folder and information of a couple of branches etc), on which I made some changes for the target hardware(added and comitted to local copy). Now in order to back this  to our server, I did a 'git archive' (git archive -o latest.zip HEAD) and generated a zip,                                --continued

Comment: which extracted and added to the second location which if I build from, is not booting. Except the .git directory from the first location, and couple of files about build version, Everything else seem to be present if I do  a diff.
- Now if I just merge the .git folder from the first location to second, kernel boots fine. 
I must admit that I am not an expert on git and I do not have a clue on what is happening in the back graound

Comment: I tried the same on my PC and everything went fine, nothing was missing. I doubt that this is git issue. Anyway, the proper way to copy your kernel repo to server is to use `git push` (via ssh protocol). First you should create empty git repo on your server using `git init --bare` command. Then you should add it as remote repo to your local kernel project with `git remote add` command. In the end you need to `git push` your branch to your remote. Refer to [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) link for details.

Comment: I had that part already done, and that is where I have my  android source checked out from. The above explained issue happens when I move kernel from the repo in oem source code to my repo in order to add to the git.

Comment: partially resolved now. The real issue is something in the build system is looking for the .git folder.After adding the archived source to new location if I  create a git repo inside the kernel folder at new location using - git init / git add- , the build starts  working. Yet to find the exact why and where s , but good for now. Thanks @Sam for your inputs.

Comment: Kernel build system shouldn't rely on `.git` at all. You can even obtain kernel copy from kernel.org as tarball, without git folder. So either you have customized build process or the issue is somewhere else.